# Internal Connector Error (1002) - The calling thread timed out while waiting for a response to unblock it.|

Tags: java, web-services, rest, glassfish

We are developing a web based application on glassfish V3. 
We have 2 application as Client(GWT + Servlets) and Service (Spring+Hibernate+Restful Webservices)

GWT call servlet and servlet connects to Service layer. One person getting one request is working well but when GUI start to get more requests or more peoples sign in and taking data from server, Servlet starts to waiting on service connection and at last taking error message below.

> "Internal Connector Error (1002) - The
>   calling thread timed out while waiting
>   for a response to unblock it."

In that case, should we give up using restful webservices between client and service?
Or is there any way to solve this problem?
Or may EJB be more efficient way to develop this architecture?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We noticed that this problem occures when the Client layer(Servlets) and Service Layer on the same machine(same server, domain).

A loop occures while connecting to web service.

So the solution is simple. 
We have created 2 domain, deployed client to first domain and deployed service to second domain. So no more waiting queue and above error have disappeared.

I hope it helps others in same case.

Answer (score 0):

you wont get this kind of error as long as you pay attention to always include the following, when you use the ClientResource RestLet class in your client-side code:

```
ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(uri);
//please substitute the line below with any other kind of request you need to forward
Representation response = cr.put(json);

if (response != null) {
  try {
        <something>
   }finally {
    response.exhaust();
    response.release();
        cr.release(); 
   }
```

Also, on the server side, you might want to check that there is no further HTTP connection to external resources created without a connection timeout set up (which can otherwise cause the server to take longer for replying)